# Singletone in next js on server side

Tags: next.js, singleton

I tried to use @singleton() on server side in next.js and it class run some action by setTimemout.
But this is class dont created as singletone and created every container.resolve() and as result i have many requests.

```
@singleton() export class PriceProvider {   public constructor() {
    setInterval(() => void this.load(), INTERVAL);
    void this.load();   } }
```

Also I tried to save in appGlobalThis

```
const appGlobalThis = globalThis as unknown as {   priceProviderStarted: boolean; };

export class PriceProvider {
  public constructor(
    private readonly config: Config,
    private readonly raceRepository: RaceRepository,
  ) {
    if (!appGlobalThis.priceProviderStarted) {
      appGlobalThis.priceProviderStarted = true;
      void this.step();
    }
  }
```

But priceProvider run step every time